# ReactJS layout component with dynamic child components

Tags: javascript, layout, dynamic, components, reactjs

Using React 0.12.2 and given a layout component, e.g. a tray:

```
<div className="tray">
    <div className="tray__item tray__item--left" data-width="260px">
        Load a component in the left tray
    </div>
    <div className="tray__item tray__item--center">
        Load a component in the center tray
    </div>
    <div className="tray__item tray__item--right" data-width="100%">
        Load a component in the right tray
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to insert arbitrary components into each of the contents, passing them as args to this component.

Perhaps something like:

```
<Tray left={Component1} center={Component2} right={Component3}/>
```

I would also like to know how to pass an unknown amount of components e.g:

```
<Carousel items={Component1,Component2,Component3,Component4}/>
```

Just to be clear - these container components are "dumb" - they only care about sliding content - you should be able to pass whatever content (components) you want to them.

How can I do that and then render them? Thanks.

Comment: You can pass arrays as properties like this:
`items={[Component1,Component2,Component3,Component4]}`

Comment: Thanks @SimpleJ - pretty obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the render method of Tray you can do

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="tray">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Then in the component where your Tray lives you can do

```
<Tray>
  <TrayItem position="left"/>
  <TrayItem position="center"/>
  <TrayItem position="right"/>
</Tray>
```

You should be able to keep nesting this pattern, i.e.

```
<Tray>
  <TrayItem position="left">
     <SomeComponent/>
  </TrayItem>

  <TrayItem position="center">
     <div>
       <AnotherComponent/>
     </div>
  </TrayItem>

  <TrayItem position="right"/>
</Tray>
```

In this case TrayItem's render should also include `{this.props.children}`

The general principle is, you can put arbitrary components inside other components as long as the container component's render includes `{this.props.children}`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer Adam Stone + SimpleJ.

```
var Tray = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="tray">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var TrayItem = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="tray__item">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

<Tray>
    <TrayItem>
        <ComponentA/>
        <ComponentAB/>
    </TrayItem>
    <TrayItem>
        <ComponentB/>
    </TrayItem>
    <TrayItem>
        <ComponentC/>
    </TrayItem>
</Tray>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should just create a container component that has multiple child components in its render function. You never want to pass a component in as a prop

Comment: I do not know what these child components are though - the component is "dumb"

Comment: How do you not know what they are? can you give an example on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: If I am making a re-useable tray component, it's only concern is that it slides content, it does not care what that content is - I want to be able to use that component in multiple places and tell it what components will go inside it where it is used

Comment: you should have an array of data that gets passed into it, not full on components. I get where your going, but not fully. What exactly are you making?